# Найти последний вид активности за каждый день

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Есть таблица вида:

```
CREATE TABLE actions (
    user VARCHAR2(10),
    action VARCHAR2(10),
    data TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO actions
VALUES
    ('user_1', 'like', '2000-04-11 11:00'),
    ('user_1', 'message', '2000-04-11 12:00'),
    ('user_1', 'repost', '2000-04-11 13:00'),
    ('user_1', 'message', '2000-04-12 21:00'),
    ('user_2', 'comment', '2000-04-12 22:00'),
    ('user_2', 'message', '2000-04-12 23:00'),
    ('user_2', 'message', '2000-04-14 11:00');
```

Нужно для каждого дня определить последний вид активности юзера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM actions
GROUP BY user, strftime('%d', data)
HAVING MAX(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если версия СУБД поддерживает оконные функции, то так:

```
SELECT user, action
FROM (
    SELECT user
      , action
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY data DESC) AS rn
    FROM actions
) AS t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT action 
FROM actions 
WHERE user = 'user_1' 
    AND data = (
       SELECT MAX(data) 
       FROM actions 
       WHERE user = 'user_1'
    )
```

Comment: Надо для каждого уникального юзера (их 2) и за каждую уникальную дату (их 3).
Всего получается три строки в ответе.

Comment: Не совсем внимательно вопрос прочел, сорри. Но то, что я упомянул выше, это уже хотя бы полурешение...

Comment: @Alexey так доработайте чутка. надо заджойнить на позапрос (производная таблица) с группировкой по юзеру+макс